# Intent: Avoiding memory leaks when one instantiates an Intent, by using getApplicationContext()?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-context

In the official documentation (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#Intent(java.lang.String,%2520android.net.Uri for the method `public Intent (Context packageContext, Class<?> cls`), we can read:

> packageContext    Context: A Context of the application package implementing this class.

This Stackoverflow answer [What's packageContext in Intent#(Context packageContext, Class<?> cls)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5604209/whats-packagecontext-in-intentcontext-packagecontext-class-cls) precises what this definition means:

> You can pass any Context object you got from any of you application's classes. So you can either use an Activity, Service object or you can call getApplicationContext() and pass the returned Context object to the Intent constructor.

Even if an `Intent` is something very shorted-live, should we use `getApplicationContext` instead of `getActivity` in order to avoid memory leaks (so that we avoid to keep the reference to the activity, which could be wanted to be removed from RAM)?

Example, in a fragment class, called after the activity was created to avoid a `NullPointerException`:

`startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), SplashScreen.class));`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't matter, the context is not "held" by the Intent. It's just used to look something up (iirc, the name of the package).

Comment: Yes, That's what I was saying ("the intent is very shorted-live"). But conceptually, it would be better to use `getApplicationContext` since the `Intent` can last outbound the activity's life, no?

Comment: No, the Intent does not hold the context AT ALL, so it doesn't matter how long the Intent lives. The context is just used in the constructor, it's never put in an attribute.

Comment: Ah ok thanks. Where did you have this piece of information?

Comment: From the sources :)  I remembered reading the code some years ago and telling myself: "ok, so it's not using the context for anything deep, it just needs it to get the name of the app package". Actually, the `Intent` constructor only uses the context to create a `ComponentName`, and you can see that all it does is call `getPackageName` on the context: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/content/ComponentName.java